# combine two lists to PCollection

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, nlp, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using Apache Beam. When writing to tfRecord I need to include the ID of the item along with its text and embedding.
The tutorial works with just one list of text but I also have a list of the IDs to match the list of text so I was wondering how I could pass the ID to the following function:

```
  def to_tf_example(entries):
  examples = []

  text_list, embedding_list = entries
  for i in range(len(text_list)):
    text = text_list[i]
    embedding = embedding_list[i]

    features = {
        # need to pass in ID here like so:
        'id': tf.train.Feature(
            bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[ids.encode('utf-8')])),
        'text': tf.train.Feature(
            bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[text.encode('utf-8')])),
        'embedding': tf.train.Feature(
            float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=embedding.tolist()))
    }
  
    example = tf.train.Example(
        features=tf.train.Features(
            feature=features)).SerializeToString(deterministic=True)
  
    examples.append(example)
  
  return examples
```

My first thought was just to include the ids in the text column of my database and then extract them via slicing or regex or something but was wondering if there was a better way, I assume converting to a PCollection but don't know where to start. Here is the pipeline:

```
    with beam.Pipeline(args.runner, options=options) as pipeline:
        query_data = pipeline | 'Read data from BigQuery' >> 
        beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(project='my-project', query=get_data(args.limit), use_standard_sql=True))
        # list of texts
        text = query_data | 'get list of text' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x['text'])
        # list of ids
        ids = query_data | 'get list of ids' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x['id'])
    
        ( text
            | 'Batch elements' >> util.BatchElements(
            min_batch_size=args.batch_size, max_batch_size=args.batch_size)
            | 'Generate embeddings' >> beam.Map(
            generate_embeddings, args.module_url, args.random_projection_matrix)
            | 'Encode to tf example' >> beam.FlatMap(to_tf_example)
            | 'Write to TFRecords files' >> beam.io.WriteToTFRecord(
            file_path_prefix='{0}'.format(args.output_dir),
            file_name_suffix='.tfrecords')
        )

        query_data | 'Convert to entity and write to datastore' >> beam.Map(
                lambda input_features: create_entity(
                    input_features, args.kind))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I altered generate_embeddings to return List[int], List[string], List[List[float]] and then used the following function to pass the list of ids and text in:

```
 def generate_embeddings_for_batch(batch, module_url, random_projection_matrix):
  embeddings = generate_embeddings([x['id'] for x in batch], [x['text'] for x in batch], module_url, random_projection_matrix)
  return embeddings
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I'll assume `generate_embeddings` has the signature `List[str], ... -> (List[str], List[List[float]])`

What you want to do is avoid splitting your texts and ids into separate PCollections. So you might want to write something like

```
def generate_embeddings_for_batch(
    batch,
    module_url,
    random_projection_matrix) -> Tuple[int, str, List[float]]:
  embeddings = generate_embeddings(
      [x['text'] for x in batch], module_url, random_projection_matrix)
  text_to_embedding = dict(embeddings)
  for id, text in batch:
    yield x['id'], x['text'], text_to_embedding[x['text']]
```

From there you should be able to write to_tf_example.

It would probably make sense to look at using [TFX](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx).

Comment: In the end I changed generate_embeddings to return List[int], List[string], List[List[float]]. So then just passed the ids via list comprehension. thanks for the suggestions.